# Split large SAS dataset into smaller datasets

Tags: macros, split, sas

I need some assistance with splitting a large SAS dataset into smaller datasets.

Each month I'll have a dataset containing a few million records. This number will vary from month to month. I need to split this dataset into multiple smaller datasets containing 250,000 records each. For example, if I have 1,050,000 records in the original dataset then I need the end result to be 4 datasets containing 250,000 records and 1 dataset containing 50,000 records.

From what I've been looking at it appears this will require using macros. Unfortunately I'm fairly new to SAS (unfamiliar with using macros) and don't have a lot of time to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on Joe's answer, maybe you could try something like this :

```
%MACRO SPLIT(DATASET);

%LET DATASET_ID = %SYSFUNC(OPEN(&DATASET.));
%LET NOBS = %SYSFUNC(ATTRN(&DATASET__ID., NLOBS));
%LET NB_DATASETS = %SYSEVALF(&NOBS. / 250000, CEIL);

DATA 
  %DO I=1 %TO &NB_DATASETS.;
    WANT&I. 
  %END;;

  SET WANT;

  %DO I=1 %TO &NB_DATASETS.;

    %IF &I. > 1 %THEN %DO; ELSE %END; IF _N_ LE 2.5E5 * &I. THEN OUTPUT WANT&I.;

  %END;
RUN;
%MEND SPLIT;
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up doing in the end. Thanks.

Comment: Since my edit was not approved for changing the answer too much, I'd like to point out here that there are some minor improvements/corrections to be made: 1) It would be a good idea to also close the dataset to prevent it from locking later. 2) SET WANT; should be SET &DATASET; 3) (Nice to have) Both the number of obs per dataset and the names of those new datasets could be additional macro parameters.

Comment: @Yoh, you should write a new answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without macros at all, if you don't mind asking for datasets that may not exist, and have a reasonable bound on things.

```
data want1 want2 want3 want4 want5 want6 want7 want8 want9;
if _n_ le 2.5e5 then output want1;
else if _n_ le 5e5 then output want2;
else if _n_ le 7.5e5 then output want3;
... etc....
run;
```

Macros would make that more efficient to program and cleaner to read, but wouldn't change how it actually runs in reality.

Comment: True, I could do it something like that. Unfortunately I won't know how many records to account for...it could be 1 million or 10 million or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without macros, using CALL EXECUTE(). It creates SAS-code as text strings and then executes it, after your "manually written" code completed.

```
data _null_;
    if 0 then set have nobs=n;
    do i=1 to ceil(n/250000);
        call execute (cats("data want",i)||";");
        call execute ("set have(firstobs="||(i-1)*250000+1||" obs="||i*250000||");");
        call execute ("run;");
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first result on Google is from the SAS User Group International (SUGI)
These folks are your friends.

The article is here:
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p083-27.pdf

The code is:

```
%macro split(ndsn=2); 
data %do i = 1 %to &ndsn.; dsn&i. %end; ; 
 retain x; 
 set orig nobs=nobs; 
 if _n_ eq 1 
 then do; 
 if mod(nobs,&ndsn.) eq 0 
 then x=int(nobs/&ndsn.); 
 else x=int(nobs/&ndsn.)+1; 
 end; 
 if _n_ le x then output dsn1; 
 %do i = 2 %to &ndsn.; 
 else if _n_ le (&i.*x) 
 then output dsn&i.; 
 %end; 
 run; 
%mend split; 

%split(ndsn=10);
```

All you need to do is replace the 10 digit in "%split(ndsn=10);" with the number you require.
In Line 4, "set orig nobs=nobs;", simply replace orig with your dataset name.

Hey presto!

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient option, if you have room in memory to store *one* of the smaller datasets, is a hash solution.  Here's an example using basically what you're describing in the question:

```
data in_data;
  do recid = 1 to 1.000001e7;
    datavar = 1;
    output;
  end;
run;


data _null_;
  if 0 then set in_data;
  declare hash h_out();
  h_out.defineKey('_n_');
  h_out.defineData('recid','datavar');
  h_out.defineDone();

  do filenum = 1 by 1 until (eof);
    do _n_ = 1 to 250000 until (eof);
      set in_data end=eof;
      h_out.add();
    end;
    h_out.output(dataset:cats('file_',filenum));
    h_out.clear();
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

We define a hash object with the appropriate parameters, and simply tell it to output every 250k records, and clear it.  We could do a hash-of-hashes here also, particularly if it weren't just "Every 250k records" but some other criteria drove things, but then you'd have to fit *all* of the records in memory, not just 250k of them.

Note also that we could do this without specifying the variables explicitly, but it requires having a useful ID on the dataset:

```
data _null_;
  if 0 then set in_data;
  declare hash h_out(dataset:'in_data(obs=0)');
  h_out.defineKey('recid');
  h_out.defineData(all:'y');
  h_out.defineDone();

  do filenum = 1 by 1 until (eof);
    do _n_ = 1 to 250000 until (eof);
      set in_data end=eof;
      h_out.add();
    end;
    h_out.output(dataset:cats('file_',filenum));
    h_out.clear();
  end;
  stop;
run;
```

Since we can't use `_n_` anymore for the hash ID due to using the `dataset` option on the constructor (necessary for the `all:'y'` functionality), we have to have a record ID.  Hopefully there is such a variable, or one could be added with a view.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic approach. This requires manual adjustment of the intervals, but is easy to understand.

```
* split data;
data output1;
set df;
if 1 <= _N_ < 5 then output;
run;


data output2;
set df;
if 5 <= _N_ < 10 then output;
run;


data output3;
set df;
if 10 <= _N_ < 15 then output;
run;


data output4;
set df;
if 15 <= _N_ < 22 then output;
run;
```